Docker Container - STDOUT
I'm having an absolute nightmare and hoping someone can help. I have a ELF file which I'm deploying to a container. That file runs fine and when it runs I have it sending text to STDOUT via cout. If I run the file directly in my server it works fine and I can see the text being presented as normal. What I want to do is allow the program to run and have anyone SSH into the container and at period intervals get the text that the program is producing. I've tried all sorts.
The main one I thought about doing is exporting the STDOUT to a log file in /var/log/sample.log which works fine and then tailing it via -f as a background process but that doesn't seem to be working when I then SSH into the container.
Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get around this?

For anyone else struggling with this I was on the right track with tailing the log file out using bashrc unfortunately I missed the & at the end of the line to background it. All you need to do is add this single line of code to .bashrc
Tail -f /var/log/sample.log &
